# Grouping / Aggregation in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I run this (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
SELECT [UserId]
      ,[StateDuration]
      ,[StatusKey]  
FROM [AgentActivityLog]
WHERE [StatusDateTime] between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
```

I get a row per UserId like this:
UserId  StatusDateTime  StatusKey

```
cfrinco      3456   Meeting
echartl      23456  Available
mbarbewar    3256   Lunch
bsantiago    46565  Available
bsantiago    79     Follow Up
fburger      5464   Available
```

Which tells me the time in seconds that each user was at a each status.

**Of course, there will be many entries per `UserId` per date.**
In other words, a user, in a day, will go from Available to Meeting to Available to Lunch to Available, etc.

What I want to do is to total the time in seconds per `UserId`, per `StatusKey`, per calendar day. So it would look something like this:

```
cfrinco      3456   Meeting       '2012-01-01'
cfrinco      45678  Available     '2012-01-01'
cfrinco      7845   Meeting       '2012-01-02'
cfrinco      32541  Available     '2012-01-02'
cfrinco      4455   Meeting       '2012-01-03'
cfrinco      12456  Available     '2012-01-03'
fburger      3456   Meeting       '2012-01-01'
fburger      75489  Available     '2012-01-01'
fburger      3541   Lunch         '2012-01-01'
fburger      5486   Meeting       '2012-01-02'
fburger      64587  Available     '2012-01-02'
fburger      3614   Lunch         '2012-01-02'
fburger      3225   Meeting       '2012-01-03'
fburger      35414  Available     '2012-01-03'
fburger      3745   Lunch         '2012-01-03'
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. After some research of different answers in stackoverflow and putting them together, I got it.

```
SELECT
UserId, SUM(StateDuration) SumStateDuration, StatusKey,
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, StatusDateTime)) StatusDate
FROM [AgentActivityLog]
WHERE StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'

GROUP BY
 UserId,
 DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, StatusDateTime)),
 StatusKey
```

The key part was to 
(a) get just the date out of datetime column and (b) group by it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data grouped by User ID, Status, and Date, then do something like:

```
SELECT
 UserId
 SUM(StateDuration),
 StatusKey,
 StatusDateTime
FROM AgentActivityLog
WHERE StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY
 UserId,
 StatusDateTime,
 StatusKey
```

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. There will be many entries per `UserId` per date. In other words, a user, in a day, will go from Available to Meeting to Available to Lunch to Available, etc. Thanks!